# RESET autoincrement value daily Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, lamp

Hi I'm working on a server based POS using LAMP server , I want the receipt column(marked as "ticket") to reset daily, so I will start everyday with receipt No.1, I created a table

```
CREATE TABLE maestra(ticket INT KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,cliente_id INT,Movimiento DOUBLE,Fecha DATETIME,tpago INT)
```

but the value wont reset using

```
ALTER TABLE maestra AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

So that I could reset it using a sh script, how can I do this?

tx in advance

Comment: What happens to existing tickets?

Comment: I want to keep them, with repeated values , the comand ALTER TABLE maestra AUTO_INCREMENT = 1; does nothing, probably because the value I'm trying to set already exists

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that cause in your table creation, you have mentioned `ticket` as `KEY`(Which has to be since it's auto_increment). So it has to be unique.

```
CREATE TABLE maestra
(
ticket INT KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, <-- Here
cliente_id INT,
Movimiento DOUBLE,
Fecha DATETIME,tpago INT
)
```

Now even if `ALTER TABLE maestra AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;` succeeds, the moment you try insert a new row with `ticket` value `1` it will throw error `can not insert duplicate value`

Only option I see, create a script which will run daily (as scheduled job may be) and transfer the data from this table to a secondary table like and then, start inserting new ones.

```
insert into sec_table
select * from maestra
```

(OR)

Have a `datetime` column in your table where you store the Date/Time of the ticket  registration.

Comment: `KEY` in MySQL is the same as `INDEX` and is not unique.

Comment: @Arjan, true but it also must be unique cause with `KEY` you can also specify PK. As per MySQL documentation `The key attribute PRIMARY KEY can also be specified as just KEY when given in a column definition.`. See here if you have missed it http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, I had indeed missed that part of the specs.

Answer (score 1):

`AUTO_INCREMENT` columns must also be `PRIMARY KEY`s. If you don't specify that explicitly, MySQL will add it silently. So what you want is not possible, because a `PRIMARY KEY` is by definition `UNIQUE` so you cannot have more than one record with the same ticket number.

Answer (score -2):

Why not just truncate the table?

```
TRUNCATE TABLE maestra;
```

It will delete all table data and reset the auto-increment counter to 0.

Comment: I believe that will work, but I would have to make a backup of that table everyday. so that I wont lose data, isnt there a way to do it without deleting data?